# Install/Start YARN in Docker

Tags: docker, hadoop-yarn

I'm working on installing/starting YARN in docker, the major issue is YARN need to start slaves by ssh but I did not container's IP. Is there any script in YARN to start master/agent manually without ssh?

Thanks
Klaus

Comment: This might be a good start https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainerExecutor.html#Working_example_of_yarn_launched_docker_containers

Comment: @kichik , thanks. I found the related script :).